Magento 2.4.7 Placeorder with newly created store showing Deprecated Functionality: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3
I have created a new store and only when placing orderwith that store, I am getting below error:
Deprecated Functionality: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in vendor\/magento\/zend-db\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Abstract.php on line 1044 
all other stores works fine.
I have debugged the related files, all quote related data are correctly fetching and I couldn't see any null values anywhere. The store configuration also done same as others.

Can you add full error stack ?

I have debugged it and identified that the $table is NULL in the insert() function of vendor/magento/zend-db/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php file when click on the placeorder button at checkout using this store. but place order is working fine at other stores

Please try to disable all 3rd party modules and then try to place order, Thank You!

@NotEqual you might want to check if the sales-sequence-tables for the new store exist. There have been cases where they are missing, making it impossible to checkout

Thank you @simonthesorcerer! I had the same problem and your comment lead me to the right place.
Indead the table "sequence_order_2" for storeview with id 2 was missing. But this was not the only thing. Also the entries in the "sales_sequence_meta" table were missing. There you just have to insert them like this:
INSERT INTO `sales_sequence_meta` (`meta_id`, `entity_type`, `store_id`, `sequence_table`) VALUES (NULL, 'order', '2', 'sequence_order_2');

